# Is it ok to use react states as signals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I had a code that was staring a few async function that were modifing my React State. but the problem was that when launching an other function after all promises were resolved, this function did not have the updated version of my State :

```js
const [myState, setMyState] = useState<myType[]>({...});

const pendingPromises: Promise<void>[] = [];

async function asyncFunction(a: myType){
  return fs.promises.copyFile(a.currentPath, a.destination).then(() => {
    setMyState((myState) => [...myState.filter((b) => (b.id != a.id)), {...a, curentPath: a.destination}]

function saveMyState(){
  // Actually just saving it to a JSON
  console.log(myState) // This shows the original state before it has been modified by asyncFunction()
}

function mainFunction(){
  myArray.forEach((a) => pendingPromises.push(asyncFunction(a))

  Promise.all(pendingPromises).then(saveMyState)
}
```

So to solve the problem I declared a new state that I change to true when I need to call my second function:

```js
const [myState, setMyState] = useState<myType[]>({...});

const [callFunction, setCallFunction] = useState<boolean>(false);

const pendingPromises: Promise<void>[] = [];

useEffect(() => {
  if (callFunction) {
    saveMyState();
    setCallFunction(false);
  }
}, [callFunction]);

async function asyncFunction(a: myType){
  return fs.promises.copyFile(a.currentPath, a.destination).then(() => {
    setMyState((myState) => [...myState.filter((b) => (b.id != a.id)), {...a, curentPath: a.destination}]
  });

function saveMyState(){
  // Actually just saving it to a JSON file
  console.log(myState) // This shows the original state before it has been modified by asyncFunction()
}

function mainFunction(){
  myState.forEach((a) => pendingPromises.push(moveFile(a))

  Promise.all(pendingPromises).then(() => setCallFunction(true)) // calling function
}
```

This is working but it doesn't feels really clean.
**Is this way of doing okay ? If not, how should I proceed ?**

Comment: Define "OK." ...

Comment: @RobertHarvey I want to know if this could fail sometimes, like useEffect wouldn't get that the state has changed. And I want to know if there's a cleaner way of doing this ?

Comment: Another problem is that if this code is the body of a component, `pendingPromises` is emphemeral. It shouldn't be declared at the top-level of the component. If you need it between renders, it should be state or a ref or similar. If not, it should be within the function that needs it. A proper [mcve] would really help us help you, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: I assume you're calling `setMyState()` inside of `asyncFunction` because you want to rerender after _each_ async operation is complete? Otherwise, if you just care about the final result and rendering that, then instead of calling `setMyState()` within `asyncFunction` you may be better off accumulating all your async values that you've obtained within `mainFunction()` and using the array result that gets passed to the `doStuffWithUpdatedState` callback to build your final state value (and then calling `setMyState()`) within there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm going to try that

Comment: @NickParsons `asyncFunction` is actually `fs.promises.copyFile()` and I'm changing my state according to the results

Comment: @AntoninL - Does `doStuffWithUpdatedState` change state?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no it doesn't

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did not make a reproductible example as it seems to only support class components. But I improved my post by making it more realistic

Comment: @AntoninL - Thanks for updating the question. I've updated my answer to change `doStuffWithUpdatedState` to `saveMyState`, and to add a new (first) option now we know what the function does. :-) (Ideally in future, probably best not to change the name of the function when it's used by existing answers. But thanks again for the additional information, and generally for answering the questions we've had!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often in this situation, the function in question is changing state, so using the [callback form](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) of the state setter is the simple solution. But `saveMyState` doesn't change state, it just uses it.

That being the case, it's probably best not to cause a re-render by setting that state flag just to call the function.

Here are some alternatives:

1. Since `saveMyState`'s job is to save the current state as JSON, you might consider just doing that **any** time the state changes, rather than allowing the JSON version to remain out of sync with the state for a period of time. To do that, don't call it from `Promise.all(/*...*/).then` at all, just do the work in `useEffect`:

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
       // ...save `myState` as JSON...
   }, [myState]); // <== Triggers the effect callback when `myState` changes
   ```
2. You *can* go ahead and use the callback form of the state setter anyway, just returning the same state it received, making the state update call do nothing:

   ```
   function saveMyState(){
       setMyState((state) => {
           // ...save `state` as JSON...
           return state; // Return state unchanged
       });
   }
   ```

   I've done that a couple of times, but never been *really* happy with it. :-)
3. You can use a `ref` to always have access to up-to-date state:

   ```
   const [myState, setMyState] = useState<myType>({/*...*/});
   const refMyState = useRef(myState); // Using the initial value here just
                                       // makes the types easier
   refMyState.current = myState;       // Make sure the ref is always up-to-date
                                       // (You *could* put the update in a
                                       // `useEffect`, but that's needlessly
                                       // complex.)

   // ...

   function saveMyState(){
       const state = refMyState.current;
       // ...save `state` as JSON...
   }
   ```
4. Use other mechanisms for storing `myState` rather than `useState`, such as [Redux](https://redux.js.org). *(Doing so is a big enough change I won't do an example, their docs have it covered.)*

Answer (score -1):

The benefit of a signal is that no matter how many react children you have, only those listening on the signal do a re-render. Everything that includes that component above, whether its a context or useRef, all of its chain will re-render on any change.

If you want to create signals - create an observer on the window object which any react component can listen to. Something like a javascript proxy. Here is an example:

https://github.com/inspiraller/react-proxy